# Add extra item to drop down menu plugin. "Layers menu from project" plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I have created a drop down menu in QGIS. The code is mainly from the "Layers menu from project" plugin. I have cleaned it so it only have the drop down.

My problem is that I will like to add an extra item to the drop down (a "Info" item, or "about the plugin"), but I can't figure out where to add it to the code.

I added the following just above return yaLayer, but it resulted in a 'Extra item' for each other item in the drop down.

```
menu.addSeparator()
menu.addMenuitem('Extra item')
```

Does anyone know where to add it or give a hint?

Entire code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *

from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtXml

from menu_conf_dlg import menu_conf_dlg

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources


def getFirstChildByTagNameValue(elt, tagName, key, value):
    nodes = elt.elementsByTagName(tagName)
    for node in (nodes.at(i) for i in range(nodes.size())):
        idNode = node.namedItem(key)
        if idNode and value == idNode.firstChild().toText().data():
            # layer founds
            return node

    return None

class menu_from_project: 

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.path = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(__file__)).path()
        self.iface = iface
        self.toolBar = None

        # new multi projects var
        self.projects = []
        self.menubarActions = []
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.optionTooltip = (False)
        self.optionCreateGroup = (False)
        self.optionLoadAll = (False)
        self.read()       

        # default lang
        locale = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")
        self.myLocale = locale[0:2]


    def store(self):
        s = QSettings()
        s.remove("menu_from_project/projectFilePath")

        index = 0

        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionTooltip", (self.optionTooltip))
        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionCreateGroup", (self.optionCreateGroup))
        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionLoadAll", (self.optionLoadAll))

        s.beginWriteArray("menu_from_project/projects")
        for project in self.projects:
            s.setArrayIndex(index)
            s.setValue("file", project["file"])
            s.setValue("name", project["name"])
            index = index + 1

        s.endArray()

    def read(self):
        s = QSettings()
        try:
            # old single project conf         
            filePath = s.value("menu_from_project/projectFilePath", "")

            if filePath:
                title = str(filePath).split('/')[-1]
                title = str(title).split('.')[0]
                self.projects.append({"file":filePath, "name":title})
                self.store()
            else:
                # patch : lecture ancienne conf
                size = s.beginReadArray("projects")
                for i in range(size):
                    s.setArrayIndex(i)
                    file = ((s.value("file").toString()))
                    name = ((s.value("name").toString()))
                    if file:
                        self.projects.append({"file":file, "name":(name)})
                s.endArray()

                size = s.beginReadArray("menu_from_project/projects")
                for i in range(size):
                    s.setArrayIndex(i)
                    file = s.value("file", "")
                    name = s.value("name", "")
                    if file != "":
                        self.projects.append({"file":file, "name":name})

                s.endArray()

            self.optionTooltip = s.value("menu_from_project/optionTooltip", (True), type=bool)

            # create group option only since 1.9
            self.optionCreateGroup = s.value("menu_from_project/optionCreateGroup", (False), type=bool)
            self.optionLoadAll = s.value("menu_from_project/optionLoadAll", (False), type=bool)

        except:
            pass

    def isAbsolute(self, doc):
        absolute = False
        try:
            props = doc.elementsByTagName("properties")
            if props.count()==1:
                node = props.at(0)
                pathNode = node.namedItem("Paths")
                absoluteNode = pathNode.namedItem("Absolute")
                absolute = ("true" == absoluteNode.firstChild().toText().data())
        except:
            pass

        return  absolute

    def _actionHovered(self, action): 
        tip = action.toolTip() 
        if (tip != "-"):
            QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), tip)
        else: 
            QToolTip.hideText()

    def getMaplayerDomFromQgs(self, fileName, layerId):
        xml = file(unicode(fileName)).read()
        doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
        doc.setContent(xml)

        maplayers = doc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")
        for ml in (maplayers.item(i) for i in range(maplayers.size())):
            idelt = ml.namedItem("id")
            id = ""

            if idelt and layerId == idelt.firstChild().toText().data():
                return ml

        return None

    def addMenuItem(self, filename, node, menu, domdoc):
        yaLayer = False
        initialFilename = filename

        if node == None:
            return yaLayer

        element = node.toElement()

        # if legendlayer tag
        if node.nodeName() == "legendlayer":
            try:
                legendlayerfileElt = element.firstChild().firstChildElement("legendlayerfile")
                layerId = legendlayerfileElt.attribute("layerid")
                action = QAction(element.attribute("name"), self.iface.mainWindow())

                if (self.optionTooltip == (True)): 
                    try:
                        maplayers = domdoc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")
                        for ml in (maplayers.item(i) for i in range(maplayers.size())):
                            idelt = ml.namedItem("id")
                            id = ""

                            if (idelt != None):
                                id = idelt.firstChild().toText().data()

                            attrEmbedded = ml.toElement().attribute("embedded", "0")
                            if (attrEmbedded == "1"):
                                id = ml.toElement().attribute("id", "")

                            if (id == layerId):
                                # embedded layers ?
                                embeddedFilename = ""
                                if (attrEmbedded == "1"):
                                    try:
                                        embeddedFilename = ml.toElement().attribute("project", "")
                                        # read embedded project
                                        if not self.absolute and (embeddedFilename.find(".")==0):
                                            embeddedFilename = self.projectpath + "/" + embeddedFilename

                                        ml = self.getMaplayerDomFromQgs(embeddedFilename, id)
                                        filename = embeddedFilename
                                    except:
                                        pass

                                if ml != None:
                                    try:
                                        title = ml.namedItem("title").firstChild().toText().data()
                                        abstract = ml.namedItem("abstract").firstChild().toText().data()

                                        action.setStatusTip(title)
                                        if (abstract != "") and (title == ""):
                                            action.setToolTip("<p>%s</p>" % (abstract))
                                        else:
                                            if (abstract != "" or title != ""):
                                                action.setToolTip("<b>%s</b><br/>%s" % (title, abstract))
                                            else:
                                                action.setToolTip("-")
                                    except:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(id+" not found in project "+embeddedFilename, 'Extensions')

                                break
                    except:
                        pass

                menu.addAction(action)
                yaLayer = True
                helper = lambda _filename,_who,_menu: (lambda: self.do_aeag_menu(_filename, _who, _menu))
                action.triggered.connect(helper(filename, layerId, menu))
            except:
                pass

            nextNode = node.nextSibling()
            if (nextNode != None):
                # ! recursion
                self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)
        # / if element.tagName() == "legendlayer":

        # if legendgroup tag
        if node.nodeName() == "legendgroup":
            name = element.attribute("name")
            if name == "-":
                menu.addSeparator()
                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)

            elif name.startswith("-"):
                action = QAction(name[1:], self.iface.mainWindow())
                font = QFont()
                font.setBold(True)
                action.setFont(font)
                menu.addAction(action) 

                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)

            else:
                #messageLog("Group %s" % (element.attribute("name")))

                # construire sous-menu
                sousmenu = menu.addMenu('&'+element.attribute("name"))
                sousmenu.menuAction().setToolTip("-")

                childNode = node.firstChild()

                #  ! recursion
                r = self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, childNode, sousmenu, domdoc)

                if r and self.optionLoadAll and (len(sousmenu.actions()) > 1):
                    action = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Load all", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.iface.mainWindow())
                    font = QFont()
                    font.setBold(True)
                    action.setFont(font)
                    sousmenu.addAction(action) 
                    helper = lambda _filename,_who,_menu: (lambda: self.do_aeag_menu(_filename, _who, _menu))
                    action.triggered.connect(helper(None, None, sousmenu))

                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)
        # / if element.tagName() == "legendgroup":
        #below works but add a lot
        #menu.addSeparator()
        #menu.addMenuitem('actiontest')
        return yaLayer


    def addMenu(self, name, filename, domdoc):
        # main project menu
        menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
        projectMenu = QMenu('&'+name, menuBar)

        if (self.optionTooltip == (True)): 
            projectMenu.hovered.connect(self._actionHovered)

        projectAction = menuBar.addMenu(projectMenu)
        self.menubarActions.append(projectAction);

        self.absolute = self.isAbsolute(domdoc)
        self.projectpath = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(filename)).path()

        # build menu on legend schema
        legends = domdoc.elementsByTagName("legend")
        if (legends.length() > 0):
            node = legends.item(0)
            if node:
                node = node.firstChild()
                self.addMenuItem(filename, node, projectMenu, domdoc)

        # Seperate settings from actual content

    def initMenus(self):
        menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
        for action in self.menubarActions:
            menuBar.removeAction(action)
            del(action)

        self.menubarActions = []

        QgsApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        for project in self.projects:
            try:
                xml = file(unicode(project["file"])).read()
                doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
                doc.setContent(xml)

                self.addMenu(project["name"], project["file"], doc)
            except:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Menu from layer : invalid ' + str(project["file"]), 'Extensions')
                pass

        QgsApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()



    def initGui(self):          
        # build menu
    self.initMenus()




    # run method that performs all the real work
    def do_aeag_menu(self, filename, who, menu=None):
        self.canvas.freeze(True)
        self.canvas.setRenderFlag(False)
        idxGroup = None
        theLayer = None
        groupName = None
        QgsApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)

        try:
            if type(menu.parentWidget()) == QMenu and self.optionCreateGroup:
                groupName = menu.title().replace("&", "")

                idxGroup = self.iface.legendInterface().groups().index(groupName) if groupName in self.iface.legendInterface().groups() else -1

                if idxGroup < 0:
                    idxGroup = self.iface.legendInterface().addGroup(groupName, True)

            # load all layers
            if filename == None and who == None and self.optionLoadAll:
                i = 0
                for action in reversed(menu.actions()):
                    if action.text() != QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Load all", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8):
                        action.trigger()
            else:
                # read QGis project
                xml = file(unicode(filename)).read()
                doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
                doc.setContent(xml)

                # is project in relative path ?                
                absolute = self.isAbsolute(doc)

                node = getFirstChildByTagNameValue(doc.documentElement(), "maplayer", "id", who)
                if node:
                    idNode = node.namedItem("id")
                    # give it a new id (for multiple import)
                    try:
                        import uuid
                        import re
                        newLayerId = "L%s" % re.sub("[{}-]", "", QUuid.createUuid().toString())
                        idNode.firstChild().toText().setData(newLayerId)
                    except:
                        pass

                    # if relative path, adapt datasource
                    if not absolute:
                        try:
                            datasourceNode = node.namedItem("datasource")
                            datasource = datasourceNode.firstChild().toText().data()
                            providerNode = node.namedItem("provider")
                            provider = providerNode.firstChild().toText().data()

                            if provider == "ogr" and (datasource.find(".")==0):
                                projectpath = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(filename)).path()
                                newlayerpath = projectpath + "/" + datasource 
                                datasourceNode.firstChild().toText().setData(newlayerpath)
                        except:
                            pass

                    # read modified layer node
                    QgsProject.instance().read(node)

                    if self.optionCreateGroup:
                        theLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(newLayerId)

                        if idxGroup >= 0 and theLayer != None:
                            self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage("Move to group "+str(idxGroup))
                            self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(theLayer)
                            self.iface.legendInterface().moveLayer(theLayer, idxGroup)
                            self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(theLayer)


        except:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Menu from layer : invalid ' + filename, 'Extensions')
            pass

        self.canvas.freeze(False)    
        self.canvas.setRenderFlag(True)
        self.canvas.refresh()
        QgsApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()  


    def doLink( self, url ):
        if url.host() == "" :
            self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.page().currentFrame().load(url)
        else:
            QDesktopServices.openUrl( url )
```

Comment: You should create an action (QAction), and you can add this action to a menu. Look in the source code of any Python plug-in with menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the style used in the "Layers menu from project" for the other two items (`Projects configuration` and `Help`) and rename it slightly to fit your requirements.

---

## initGui()

In the `initGui()` function (*I am using the source code for the plugin*), it reads the following:

```
def initGui(self):          
    self.act_aeag_menu_config = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Projects configuration", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
    # Add actions to the toolbar
    self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.connect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)

    self.act_aeag_menu_help = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Help", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)
    self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.connect(self.do_help)

    # build menu
    self.initMenus()
```

As [Zoltan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/26288/zoltan) mentioned, we can create a QAction and add it as a menu. In the above code, it shows how the other two items are being added. So we can just copy it and change the name slightly:

```
def initGui(self):          
    self.act_aeag_menu_config = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Projects configuration", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
    # Add actions to the toolbar
    self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.connect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)

    self.act_aeag_menu_help = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Help", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)
    self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.connect(self.do_help)

    # Here we added a QAction for 'Extra item'
    self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Extra item", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem)
    self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem.triggered.connect(self.do_extraItem)
    
    # build menu
    self.initMenus()
```

---

## do_extraItem()

We need to define a function for what happens when the "Extra item" menu has been clicked. We already connected the QAction to a function called `do_extraItem()` but now we have to define this new function. Here's a simple example:

```
def do_extraItem(self):
    print "Hopefully this works!"
```

---

## unload()

Finally, to avoid creating duplicate items in the menu, we need to remove and disconnect the QAction from the menu. Here is the original source code:

```
def unload(self):
    menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
    for action in self.menubarActions:
        menuBar.removeAction(action)

    self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)

    self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.disconnect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)
    self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.disconnect(self.do_help)

    self.store()
```

Again we can repeat the similar lines of code used for our new menu item:

```
def unload(self):
    menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
    for action in self.menubarActions:
        menuBar.removeAction(action)

    self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
    self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)
    # New line added below
    self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem)

    self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.disconnect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)
    self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.disconnect(self.do_help)
    # New line added below
    self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem.triggered.disconnect(self.do_extraItem)

    self.store()
```

---

And hopefully, that should help get you started:

[image: Result]

---

**Edit:**

This is the complete script for the `menu_from_project.py` file that I edited to show the extra item. Copy/paste the whole code into the said file, reload the plugin (or QGIS) and you should see the extra menu option. Make sure to back up your original file!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *

from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtXml
from ui_browser import Ui_browser

from menu_conf_dlg import menu_conf_dlg

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources


def getFirstChildByTagNameValue(elt, tagName, key, value):
    nodes = elt.elementsByTagName(tagName)
    for node in (nodes.at(i) for i in range(nodes.size())):
        idNode = node.namedItem(key)
        if idNode and value == idNode.firstChild().toText().data():
            # layer founds
            return node
            
    return None

class menu_from_project: 

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.path = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(__file__)).path()
        self.iface = iface
        self.toolBar = None
        
        # new multi projects var
        self.projects = []
        self.menubarActions = []
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.optionTooltip = (False)
        self.optionCreateGroup = (False)
        self.optionLoadAll = (False)
        self.read()       
        
        # default lang
        locale = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")
        self.myLocale = locale[0:2]
        # dictionnary
        localePath = self.path+"/i18n/menu_from_project_" + self.myLocale + ".qm"
        # translator
        if QFileInfo(localePath).exists():
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(localePath)
            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

    def store(self):
        s = QSettings()
        s.remove("menu_from_project/projectFilePath")

        index = 0
        
        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionTooltip", (self.optionTooltip))
        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionCreateGroup", (self.optionCreateGroup))
        s.setValue("menu_from_project/optionLoadAll", (self.optionLoadAll))
        
        s.beginWriteArray("menu_from_project/projects")
        for project in self.projects:
            s.setArrayIndex(index)
            s.setValue("file", project["file"])
            s.setValue("name", project["name"])
            index = index + 1
            
        s.endArray()

    def read(self):
        s = QSettings()
        try:
            # old single project conf         
            filePath = s.value("menu_from_project/projectFilePath", "")
            
            if filePath:
                title = str(filePath).split('/')[-1]
                title = str(title).split('.')[0]
                self.projects.append({"file":filePath, "name":title})
                self.store()
            else:
                # patch : lecture ancienne conf
                size = s.beginReadArray("projects")
                for i in range(size):
                    s.setArrayIndex(i)
                    file = ((s.value("file").toString()))
                    name = ((s.value("name").toString()))
                    if file:
                        self.projects.append({"file":file, "name":(name)})
                s.endArray()

                size = s.beginReadArray("menu_from_project/projects")
                for i in range(size):
                    s.setArrayIndex(i)
                    file = s.value("file", "")
                    name = s.value("name", "")
                    if file != "":
                        self.projects.append({"file":file, "name":name})
                        
                s.endArray()
            
            self.optionTooltip = s.value("menu_from_project/optionTooltip", (True), type=bool)
            
            # create group option only since 1.9
            self.optionCreateGroup = s.value("menu_from_project/optionCreateGroup", (False), type=bool)
            self.optionLoadAll = s.value("menu_from_project/optionLoadAll", (False), type=bool)
            
        except:
            pass
        
    def isAbsolute(self, doc):
        absolute = False
        try:
            props = doc.elementsByTagName("properties")
            if props.count()==1:
                node = props.at(0)
                pathNode = node.namedItem("Paths")
                absoluteNode = pathNode.namedItem("Absolute")
                absolute = ("true" == absoluteNode.firstChild().toText().data())
        except:
            pass
        
        return  absolute

    def _actionHovered(self, action): 
        tip = action.toolTip() 
        if (tip != "-"):
            QToolTip.showText(QCursor.pos(), tip)
        else: 
            QToolTip.hideText()
      
    def getMaplayerDomFromQgs(self, fileName, layerId):
        xml = file(unicode(fileName)).read()
        doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
        doc.setContent(xml)
        
        maplayers = doc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")
        for ml in (maplayers.item(i) for i in range(maplayers.size())):
            idelt = ml.namedItem("id")
            id = ""
            
            if idelt and layerId == idelt.firstChild().toText().data():
                return ml
            
        return None
        
    def addMenuItem(self, filename, node, menu, domdoc):
        yaLayer = False
        initialFilename = filename
        
        if node == None:
            return yaLayer
            
        element = node.toElement()
        
        # if legendlayer tag
        if node.nodeName() == "legendlayer":
            try:
                legendlayerfileElt = element.firstChild().firstChildElement("legendlayerfile")
                layerId = legendlayerfileElt.attribute("layerid")
                action = QAction(element.attribute("name"), self.iface.mainWindow())
                
                if (self.optionTooltip == (True)): 
                    try:
                        maplayers = domdoc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")
                        for ml in (maplayers.item(i) for i in range(maplayers.size())):
                            idelt = ml.namedItem("id")
                            id = ""
                            
                            if (idelt != None):
                                id = idelt.firstChild().toText().data()
                            
                            attrEmbedded = ml.toElement().attribute("embedded", "0")
                            if (attrEmbedded == "1"):
                                id = ml.toElement().attribute("id", "")
                                
                            if (id == layerId):
                                # embedded layers ?
                                embeddedFilename = ""
                                if (attrEmbedded == "1"):
                                    try:
                                        embeddedFilename = ml.toElement().attribute("project", "")
                                        # read embedded project
                                        if not self.absolute and (embeddedFilename.find(".")==0):
                                            embeddedFilename = self.projectpath + "/" + embeddedFilename

                                        ml = self.getMaplayerDomFromQgs(embeddedFilename, id)
                                        filename = embeddedFilename
                                    except:
                                        pass
                            
                                if ml != None:
                                    try:
                                        title = ml.namedItem("title").firstChild().toText().data()
                                        abstract = ml.namedItem("abstract").firstChild().toText().data()
                                        
                                        action.setStatusTip(title)
                                        if (abstract != "") and (title == ""):
                                            action.setToolTip("<p>%s</p>" % (abstract))
                                        else:
                                            if (abstract != "" or title != ""):
                                                action.setToolTip("<b>%s</b><br/>%s" % (title, abstract))
                                            else:
                                                action.setToolTip("-")
                                    except:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(id+" not found in project "+embeddedFilename, 'Extensions')
                                    
                                break
                    except:
                        pass
                
                menu.addAction(action)
                yaLayer = True
                helper = lambda _filename,_who,_menu: (lambda: self.do_aeag_menu(_filename, _who, _menu))
                action.triggered.connect(helper(filename, layerId, menu))
            except:
                pass
            
            nextNode = node.nextSibling()
            if (nextNode != None):
                # ! recursion
                self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)
        # / if element.tagName() == "legendlayer":
                
        # if legendgroup tag
        if node.nodeName() == "legendgroup":
            name = element.attribute("name")
            if name == "-":
                menu.addSeparator()
                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)

            elif name.startswith("-"):
                action = QAction(name[1:], self.iface.mainWindow())
                font = QFont()
                font.setBold(True)
                action.setFont(font)
                menu.addAction(action) 

                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)
                    
            else:
                #messageLog("Group %s" % (element.attribute("name")))
                
                # construire sous-menu
                sousmenu = menu.addMenu('&'+element.attribute("name"))
                sousmenu.menuAction().setToolTip("-")

                childNode = node.firstChild()

                #  ! recursion
                r = self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, childNode, sousmenu, domdoc)

                if r and self.optionLoadAll and (len(sousmenu.actions()) > 1):
                    action = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Load all", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.iface.mainWindow())
                    font = QFont()
                    font.setBold(True)
                    action.setFont(font)
                    sousmenu.addAction(action) 
                    helper = lambda _filename,_who,_menu: (lambda: self.do_aeag_menu(_filename, _who, _menu))
                    action.triggered.connect(helper(None, None, sousmenu))
                
                nextNode = node.nextSibling()
                if (nextNode != None):
                    # ! recursion
                    self.addMenuItem(initialFilename, nextNode, menu, domdoc)
        # / if element.tagName() == "legendgroup":
                   
        return yaLayer
    
    def addMenu(self, name, filename, domdoc):
        # main project menu
        menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
        projectMenu = QMenu('&'+name, menuBar)
        
        if (self.optionTooltip == (True)): 
            projectMenu.hovered.connect(self._actionHovered)

        projectAction = menuBar.addMenu(projectMenu)
        self.menubarActions.append(projectAction);

        self.absolute = self.isAbsolute(domdoc)
        self.projectpath = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(filename)).path()

        # build menu on legend schema
        legends = domdoc.elementsByTagName("legend")
        if (legends.length() > 0):
            node = legends.item(0)
            if node:
                node = node.firstChild()
                self.addMenuItem(filename, node, projectMenu, domdoc)
    
    def initMenus(self):
        menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
        for action in self.menubarActions:
            menuBar.removeAction(action)
            del(action)
            
        self.menubarActions = []

        QgsApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
        for project in self.projects:
            try:
                xml = file(unicode(project["file"])).read()
                doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
                doc.setContent(xml)
                
                self.addMenu(project["name"], project["file"], doc)
            except:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Menu from layer : invalid ' + str(project["file"]), 'Extensions')
                pass
            
        QgsApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        
    def initGui(self):          
        self.act_aeag_menu_config = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Projects configuration", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
        # Add actions to the toolbar
        self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.connect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)

        self.act_aeag_menu_help = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Help", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)
        self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.connect(self.do_help)

        # Here we added a QAction for 'Extra item'
        self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem = QAction(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "Extra item", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)+"...", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem)
        self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem.triggered.connect(self.do_extraItem)

        # build menu
        self.initMenus()


    def do_extraItem(self):
        # Extra item function
        # Print following in the python console as a test to see if it successfully connects with the menu option
        print "Hopefully this works!"

    def unload(self):
        menuBar = self.iface.editMenu().parentWidget()
        for action in self.menubarActions:
            menuBar.removeAction(action)

        self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_config)
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_help)
        # New line added below
        self.iface.removePluginMenu(QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Layers menu from project", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8), self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem)

        self.act_aeag_menu_config.triggered.disconnect(self.do_aeag_menu_config)
        self.act_aeag_menu_help.triggered.disconnect(self.do_help)
        # New line added below
        self.act_aeag_menu_extraItem.triggered.disconnect(self.do_extraItem)

        self.store()

    def do_aeag_menu_config(self):
        dlg = menu_conf_dlg(self.iface.mainWindow(), self)
        dlg.setModal(True)
        
        dlg.show()
        result = dlg.exec_()
        del dlg
        
        if result != 0:
            self.initMenus()

    # run method that performs all the real work
    def do_aeag_menu(self, filename, who, menu=None):
        self.canvas.freeze(True)
        self.canvas.setRenderFlag(False)
        idxGroup = None
        theLayer = None
        groupName = None
        QgsApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)

        try:
            if type(menu.parentWidget()) == QMenu and self.optionCreateGroup:
                groupName = menu.title().replace("&", "")

                idxGroup = self.iface.legendInterface().groups().index(groupName) if groupName in self.iface.legendInterface().groups() else -1
                
                if idxGroup < 0:
                    idxGroup = self.iface.legendInterface().addGroup(groupName, True)
    
            # load all layers
            if filename == None and who == None and self.optionLoadAll:
                i = 0
                for action in reversed(menu.actions()):
                    if action.text() != QApplication.translate("menu_from_project", "&Load all", None, QApplication.UnicodeUTF8):
                        action.trigger()
            else:
                # read QGis project
                xml = file(unicode(filename)).read()
                doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
                doc.setContent(xml)

                # is project in relative path ?                
                absolute = self.isAbsolute(doc)

                node = getFirstChildByTagNameValue(doc.documentElement(), "maplayer", "id", who)
                if node:
                    idNode = node.namedItem("id")
                    # give it a new id (for multiple import)
                    try:
                        import uuid
                        import re
                        newLayerId = "L%s" % re.sub("[{}-]", "", QUuid.createUuid().toString())
                        idNode.firstChild().toText().setData(newLayerId)
                    except:
                        pass

                    # if relative path, adapt datasource
                    if not absolute:
                        try:
                            datasourceNode = node.namedItem("datasource")
                            datasource = datasourceNode.firstChild().toText().data()
                            providerNode = node.namedItem("provider")
                            provider = providerNode.firstChild().toText().data()
                        
                            if provider == "ogr" and (datasource.find(".")==0):
                                projectpath = QFileInfo(os.path.realpath(filename)).path()
                                newlayerpath = projectpath + "/" + datasource 
                                datasourceNode.firstChild().toText().setData(newlayerpath)
                        except:
                            pass
                    
                    # read modified layer node
                    QgsProject.instance().read(node)
                            
                    if self.optionCreateGroup:
                        theLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(newLayerId)
                        
                        if idxGroup >= 0 and theLayer != None:
                            self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().showMessage("Move to group "+str(idxGroup))
                            self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(theLayer)
                            self.iface.legendInterface().moveLayer(theLayer, idxGroup)
                            self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(theLayer)
                    
                            
        except:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Menu from layer : invalid ' + filename, 'Extensions')
            pass
        
        self.canvas.freeze(False)    
        self.canvas.setRenderFlag(True)
        self.canvas.refresh()
        QgsApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
      
       
    def do_help(self):
        try:
            self.hdialog = QDialog()
            self.hdialog.setModal(True)
            self.hdialog.ui = Ui_browser()
            self.hdialog.ui.setupUi(self.hdialog)
            
            if os.path.isfile(self.path+"/help_"+self.myLocale+".html"):
                self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.setUrl(QUrl(self.path+"/help_"+self.myLocale+".html"))
            else:
                self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.setUrl(QUrl(self.path+"/help.html"))

            self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateExternalLinks) # Handle link clicks by yourself
            self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.linkClicked.connect(self.doLink)
            
            self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.page().currentFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(Qt.Vertical, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            
            self.hdialog.show()
            result = self.hdialog.exec_()
            del self.hdialog
        except:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(sys.exc_info()[0], 'Extensions')
            pass
        
    def doLink( self, url ):
        if url.host() == "" :
            self.hdialog.ui.helpContent.page().currentFrame().load(url)
        else:
            QDesktopServices.openUrl( url )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think the anser it righ. i think it works with that plugin as you show. But i cant add it to my code, i dont now where to put the extra stuff. Du you have any inputs if you take a look at the code i have in my question? Thanks

Comment: @student - Most welcome, I've edited the post to include the complete script I used. Back up your original file and replace the code with the one above and test it out :)

Comment: Thank again. I just marked it at correct. My next problem is to add the extra item the correct place. But i might come back to that.

Comment: @student - Most welcome! Glad it was helpful =)