# How to create sub-menus in QGIS 3 plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm trying to create a sub-menu in a QGIS plugin like in the image. I found this [Add extra item to drop down menu plugin. "Layers menu from project" plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220994/add-extra-item-to-drop-down-menu-plugin-layers-menu-from-project-plugin) but I'm using QGIS 3 and PyQT5 and I don't know how to adapt it. 
This is my code:

```
def initGui(self):
  icon = os.path.join(os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'logo.png'))
  self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon), 'Select Feature', self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
  self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&Select Feature', self.action)
  self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.first_start = True

def unload(self):
  self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.iface.removePluginMenu('&Select Feature', self.action)  
  del self.action
```

EDIT: I solved in this way, but I'm wondering if there's a better way

```
def initGui(self):
  icon = os.path.join(os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'logo.png'))
  self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon), 'Select Feature', self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.action2 = QAction(QIcon(icon), 'Select Feature2', self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
  self.action.triggered.connect(self.run2)
  self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&Select Feature', self.action)
  self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&Select Feature', self.action2)
  self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.first_start = True

def unload(self):
  self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.iface.removePluginMenu('&Select Feature', self.action) 
  self.iface.removePluginMenu('&Select Feature2', self.action2) 
  del self.action
  del self.action2
```

[image]

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/232859/49538 and your screenshot isn't from QGIS 3.

Comment: Thanks, I know that isn't from QGIS 3 but I want the same menu

Comment: I think you should post your solution as a proper answer. That's how I achieve the same goal in a plugin of mine (see [code snippet](https://github.com/gacarrillor/InvisibleLayersAndGroups/blob/master/invisibleLayersAndGroups.py#L40-L56)). You have one thing to adjust: In the last call to `removePluginMenu` you should use `"&Select Feature"` (without the '2'). That's all. And always remember, one great way to learn PyQGIS is looking at how other plugin authors did it. So, next time, pick a plugin that does what you want, examine its code and adapt it to yours. That's how programming works :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll sure do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is code is a working answer:

```
def initGui(self):
  icon = os.path.join(os.path.join(cmd_folder, 'logo.png'))
  self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon), 'Select Feature', self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.action2 = QAction(QIcon(icon), 'Select Feature2', self.iface.mainWindow())
  self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
  self.action.triggered.connect(self.run2)
  self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&Select Feature', self.action)
  self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&Select Feature', self.action2)
  self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.first_start = True

def unload(self):
  self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
  self.iface.removePluginMenu('&Select Feature', self.action) 
  self.iface.removePluginMenu('&Select Feature', self.action2) 
  del self.action
  del self.action2
```